TP223 replacing a button?
I have a button which does some resistor-alteration:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now I wish to replace SW with TP223 (link):

On page2, datasheet mentions TP223 has CMOS output on Q.
I wish to supply TP223 from battery (3V), which is perfectly suitable for it.
How could I replace SW, with its CMOS-output? Easiest would be a relay, but I'm curious if there is any other (simpler) solution.

what do you mean by resistor-alteration? ... is that the actual circuit?

It's a sample. Consider a circuit with constant 100R resistance, and SW alters it to 50R.

The TP223 can't be used directly for your task of "resistor alteration". The simplest way would be to use a transistor as a switch:

Now you can use the TP223 to drive the INPUT.

Why R2 is only 98R?

The 98R is because the 2N7002 has typical Rds(on) of 2R. You can choose a transistor with Rds(on) in milli-Ohm range and select the R2 close to 100R.

In case I have higher supply than 5V, can I still use your solution? Which parameter shall I check in this case (for 2N7002)?
